# Code to redirect a page and open a new tab?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Essentially what I'm trying to do is set up a code that will open a new page (weather.com) and redirect the current page to google.com if the escape key is pressed.

```
function main() {
    (document).on("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.which = 27) {
         window.open ("https://weather.com/", "_newtab")
         window.location.replace ("https://www.google.com/")}
      }
  );
}
```

When I run the current code, nothing happens. I'm very new to Javascript and Tampermonkey, so have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: You are not  comparing `if (event.which = 27) {` you are assigning. Compare then both by `if (event.which == 27) {`

Answer (score -1):

This may resolve the problem.

```
function main(){
    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        if (event.which == 27) {
            window.open ("https://weather.com/", "_newtab")
            window.location.replace ("https://www.google.com/")}
        }
    }
}
main();
```